# Can I log flight time while I am a student?

Tags: flight-training, logging

If I were to obtain a private pilot certificate, would I acquire flight hours during my training, or would I have to wait until I am certificated to obtain flight hours?

If I can log hours during training, then about how many do you think I could obtain while training to earn my private pilot certificate?

Comment: PPL requires a minimum of 40 hours of flight time, all counts towards your fight hours.  Realistically, most students need between 50 and 60 before obtaining their certificate.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! When you ask questions about logging, regulations or procedures please always tell us which country or regulations you're asking about. There are often significant differences in different places. The [tour] might also be useful if you're new to the site.

Comment: Training time is logged as PU/T 'pilot under training' and counts toward your total time.  I always log check rides and the like as PU/T

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your time you acquire during training is loggable time and counts toward your total flight time.

You will only log pilot-in-command during solo flight and during the checkride.  After passing your checkride, you will log pilot-in-command during further training in the same category and class of aircraft as well as flights during which you act as pilot-in-command.

The minimum legal requirement under part 61 for an ASEL private pilot is 40 hours.  I would shoot for efficiency and earn your certificate with the least amount of training you can, and any time you would like to pay out of pocket beyond that, fly without an instructor on board.